# how to match object-like pattern in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this:

```
var str='[{"id":"abcd","pin":5},{"id":"efgh","pin":6}]';
```

How can i match the object-like pattern in the string. I want to retrieve `{"id":"abcd","pin":"5"}`

I have tried this:

```
str.match( new RegExp('{"id":"abcd".*}'))
```

unfortunately, it matches till the end of the string which is not what i desire.
I just want to retrieve
`{"id":"abcd","pin":"5"}` by using regexp

Comment: Is it intended to do the matching given a string alone, or can the string be converted to a Javascript Object?

Comment: @JoseNuno Given a string alone. Should not be converted

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve my matching it?

Comment: You want to get a list of string object ? in your example it would be `['{"id":"abcd","pin":5}', '{"id":"efgh","pin":6}']`. Or specifically get the string object with `id:"abcd"` and `pin:5` ?

Comment: @MariusROBERT yes, i want to get string object specifically with id:abcd & pin:5

Comment: Why do you insist on using Regex here? Can't you simply use `JSON.parse(str).find(({id}) => id === 'abcd')`? (And wrap it in `JSON.stringify()` if you really need a string as the result.) Using Regex on JSON is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not wish to parse the JSON, you can use the following regular expression, but keep in mind that this only works for non-nested objects.

```js
const str = '[{"id":"abcd","pin":5},{"id":"efgh","pin":6}]';

const [found] = str.match(/\{"id":"abcd"[^\}]*\}/);

if (found) {
  console.log(found); // {"id":"abcd","pin":5}
}
```

If you want to make this a bit more dynamic, you can try the following:

```js
const str = '[{"id":"abcd","pin":5},{"id":"efgh","pin":6}]';

const findById = (jsonArrStr, id) =>
  str.match(new RegExp(`\\{"id":"${id}"[^\\}]*\\}`))?.pop();

console.log(findById(str, 'abcd')); // {"id":"abcd","pin":5}
console.log(findById(str, 'efgh')); // {"id":"efgh","pin":6}
```

If you need to retrieve the object, parse it, find it, and reserialize it.

```js
const findBy = (jsonArrStr, predicate) =>
  JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonArrStr).find(predicate));

const str = '[{"id":"abcd","pin":5},{"id":"efgh","pin":6}]';

const found = findBy(str, ({ id }) => id === 'abcd');

console.log(found); // {"id":"abcd","pin":5}
```

Comment: I'm not just checking  if id exist, I want to get the whole pattern match

Comment: @Theconcise There is no pattern though. Are you trying to match on any digit id and retrieve it?

Comment: i want to retrieve ```{"id":"abcd","pin":"5"}``` using regexp, so the starting point will be {"id":"abcd".*? and end with }

Comment: @Theconcise what about nested braces e.g. `{"id":"foo","data":{"bar":true}}`? I would just parse the JSON.

Comment: The data wont have nested braces

Comment: @Theconcise I offered various solutions.